# I can not show the value in angular select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the code HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
        <p>selected item is : {{selectedItem}}</p>
        <p> age of selected item is : {{selectedItem.age}} </p>
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items">
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is the code JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30 },{ name: 'two', age: 27 },{ name: 'three', age: 50 }];
    console.log($scope.selectedItem); //this is undefined :(
});
```

I want to show the selected value in the controller, but apparently it is undefined.

what is the correct way?

Comment: Is it firing the console.log to soon? Before it's being selected? try adding it to an on click event, like a button?

Answer (score 2):

[@JoshLeeDucks is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030576/i-can-not-show-the-value-in-angular-select#comment51962807_32030576). `$scope.selectedItem` is not defined on the scope when you are attempting to log its value. When the user assigns the property a value by selecting an element in the `<select>` input Angular will recognise that `selectedItem` is not defined and create it.

Log the value using a `$watch`:

```
console.log($scope.selectedItem); // undefined

$scope.selectedItem = 'someDefaultValue';

console.log($scope.selectedItem); // 'someDefaultValue'

$scope.$watch('selectedItem', function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue); // whatever `item.name` the user has selected
});
```

Comment: I want to return the value independently, for do other operations on the controller. any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "independently"? Once `$scope.selectedItem` has a value it can be referenced anywhere in its own and child `$scope`s.

Comment: I want the value is updated each time I make a change in value of the select. I always use the new value for other operations.

Comment: I want something:  var currentValue = $scope.selectedItem; and this will update every time I change the select in view

Comment: _"I want the value is updated each time I make a change in value of the select"_ That is the nature of the `ng-model` directive. The example I have given will _console.log_ the value of `$scope.selectedItem` each time it changes.

Comment: I need to pass this value as a parameter to another function, as I do with $scope.$watch?

Comment: You would do this: `myFunc($scope.selectedItem)`

Comment: I already tried, but the value is not updated when I change the select, always be undefined or other value initialized by default.

Comment: at the view if you are upgrading {{selectedItem}} but the controller never updated $scope.selectedItem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `selectedItem` in UI or using `console.log` when page loading. you should initialize the `selectedItem` value in your **controller**.

Like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30 },{ name: 'two', age: 27 },{ name: 'three', age: 50 }];
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
    console.log($scope.selectedItem); //this is {name: 'one', age: 30 } :(
});
```

Comment: that's fine, but I want the value is updated each time I make a change in value of the select. What should I do?

Comment: when change your selected list item automatically change your `selectedItem ` value. like: when select **two** from list items then your `selectedItem` value will be `{ name: 'two', age: 27 }`